# Is there a git hook that will run after a branch delete?

Tags: git, githooks

I want to have run a script as a git hook specifically after a branch delete. Is there one for this?

Comment: when you delete it locally? or when you `git push origin :delete-this` ?

Comment: I was thinking locally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there isn't a hook specifically for that.

If you're wanting something to be done after a branch is deleted via a push operation, you could use a post-receive hook on the server. When a push is done to that repository the hook would be called and receive on its standard input a series of lines describing the updates being done listing the previous head of the branch, the new head of the branch, and the ref name. For a delete, the new head would be a series of all zeros.

For deleting branches locally using the `-d` or `-D` options of `git branch` you could write a wrapper around that command to do whatever you want after that command has run, then train yourself to use that wrapper rather than the standard git command for doing that.